# Trait instantiation using another mixin trait

Tags: scala

It's obvious that this doesn't work:

```
trait A
val a = new A
```

since traits cannot be instantiated (if we added `{}` after `new A` then it would work, since we're creating an anonymous class).

However, this does work, and I don't know why:

```
trait A
trait B
val a = new A with B
```

Does the process of linearization automatically create an anonymous class for a base trait or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From section 5.1 of [the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#templates):

> It is possible to write a list of parents that starts with a trait
>   reference, e.g. `mt1 with ... with mtn`. In that case the list of parents
>   is implicitly extended to include the supertype of `mt1` as first parent
>   type. The new supertype must have at least one constructor that does
>   not take parameters.

So when you write `new A with B` and `A` is a trait, you're actually getting `new AnyRef with A with B`. I'm not 100% sure why the same transformation isn't applied to `new MyTrait`, but I'd guess it has something to do with avoiding confusion between traits and classes.

Comment: Exactly what my hunch was, but your reference to the spec cleared off any doubts. Thanks!